# filter out entry from enum in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following enum

```
var isLandingPage = true;

export enum Items {
    Logos = "logos",
    Colors = "colors"
}


${Object.entries(Items).map(([_key, value]) => {
    if (isLandingPage && value === Items.Logos) {
       return;
    }
}
```

When isLandingPage is set to true, I want to remove the Logos from the enum, and iterate through the enum entries using `Object.entries`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you would not simply put a condition in your iteration passing on Logos?

Comment: "When isLandingPage is set to true" <-- What's "isLandingPage"? Is this a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz I added more code to the example. I'm trying to not go through the loop if isLandingPage = true. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Did you try to use `filter` instead of `map`? And can you explain _remove the Logos from the enum_ a bit in detail? D you want to actual remove `Logos` from `Items`?

Comment: So this code is in a class, the class is being passed isLandingPage variable. Sometimes that is true or false. If its true, I don't want Object.entries to iterate through the Logos in Items.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when copy-pasted as-is into a standalone IDE. Right now my IDE has no idea what `$` and `this` and `....` is, so I have to work to figure out how best to deal with them, and hope that whatever I choose to do won't actually affect things. It's much better if we all have a common [mre] without need for such things.  Or someone could answer without trying to use an IDE, in which case you get an answer only verifiable by whatever simulacrum of TypeScript is in the mind of the answerer.

Comment: @jcalz try now. I updated the question

Comment: • May we just *ignore* whatever `${}` is? Is that like, inside some template literal?  You could always try your code in a standalone IDE and fix it yourself so we don't have to iterate this way. • Assuming it's ignorable, is there a reason you don't want to `filter()` as mentioned by @pzaenger and as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvoJRw)?

Comment: @pzaenger would you like to write up an answer here?